# mongodb update(use upsert=true) not update exists data, insert a new data?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

in my program , ten process to write mongodb by update(key, doc, upsert=true)

the "key" is mongodb index, but is not unique.

> query = {'hotelid':hotelid,"arrivedate":arrivedate,"leavedate":leavedate}
>
> where = "data.%s" % sourceid
> data_value_where = {where:value}
> self.collection.update(query,{'$set':data_value_where},True)

the "query" id the not unique index

I found sometimes the update not update exists data, but create a new data.

I write a log for update method return, the return is " {u'ok': 1.0, u'err': None, u'upserted': ObjectId('5245378b4b184fbbbea3f790'), u'singleShard': u'rs1/192.168.0.21:10000,192.168.1.191:10000,192.168.1.192:10000,192.168.1.41:10000,192.168.1.113:10000', u'connectionId': 1894107, u'n': 1, u'updatedExisting': False, u'lastOp': 5928205554643107852L}"

I modify the update method to update(query, {'$set':data_value_where},upsert=True, safe=True),  but three is no change for this question.

Comment: Who is downvoting someone trying to ask a legitimate question, but has obvious limited English typing skills? Shame on you. Why not help chjuheng re-write it so it's easier to understand?

Comment: I modify the question, and put some log on that. thanks for the all replay.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it "threadsafe", as the update itself is not done in Python, it's in the mongodb, which is built to cater many requests at once.

So in summary: You can safely do that.

Comment: Uninformed answeres: MongoDB writes are serialized.

Comment: i found in my program, same time write same data, use same key, and create duplicate documents, so i not know what happend.

Answer (score 0):

You would not end up with duplicate documents due to the operator you are using. You are actually using an atomic operator to update.

Atomic (not to be confused with SQL atomic operations of all or nothing here) operations are done in sequence so each process will never pick up a stale document or be allowed to write two ids to the same array since the document each `$set` operation picks up will have the result of the last `$set`.

The fact that you did get duplicate documents most likely means you have an error in your code.

Comment: if the update not hit the index, whether the date will be inserted ?

Comment: @chjuheng If the index is not hit (of which I do not see that happening in this update you show) then no, the date should not be inserted